# cddr: contract violation expected: (cons/c any/c pair?) given: '((4))

Tags: list, scheme, racket

```
#lang racket

(define (validar-automata automata cadena)
  (define estados (car automata))
  (define alfabeto (cadr automata))
  (define transiciones (caddr automata))
  (define estado-inicial (cadddr automata))
  (define estados-finales (caddr (cddr (cddr (cddr automata)))))

  (define (transicion estado simbolo)
    (define (transicion-aux lista-transiciones)
      (cond
        [(null? lista-transiciones) #f]
        [(and (equal? (car (car lista-transiciones)) estado)
              (equal? (cadr (car lista-transiciones)) simbolo))
         (caddr (car lista-transiciones))]
        [else
         (transicion-aux (cdr lista-transiciones))]))
    (transicion-aux transiciones))

  (define (validar-cadena cadena estado-actual)
    (if (null? cadena)
        (member estado-actual estados-finales)
        (let ((siguiente-estado (transicion estado-actual (car cadena))))
          (if siguiente-estado
              (validar-cadena (cdr cadena) siguiente-estado)
              #f))))
  
  (validar-cadena cadena estado-inicial))

(define (validar-automata-lote automata cadenas)
  (map (lambda (cadena) (validar-automata automata cadena)) cadenas))

;; Prueba con el autómata y las cadenas proporcionadas
(define automata '((0 1 2 3 4) (a b) 
      ((0 a 1) (0 b 2) (1 a 1) (1 b 3) (2 b 2) (2 a 1)
       (3 a 1) (3 b 4) (4 a 1) (4 b 2)) 0 (4)))
(define cadenas '((a b a b a a b b) (a a a a a a b)
                  (a b a b a b b) (a b)))

(displayln (validar-automata-lote automata cadenas))
```

I have a problem with this code.
In the line `(define estados-finales (caddr (cddr (cddr (cddr automata)))))` it show me an error that's says:

```
cddr: contract violation
  expected: (cons/c any/c pair?)
  given: '((4))
```

This code is used to receive an automaton as a deep list and validate some expressions with another deep list that is given to it. It must return true or false, if the expression is satisfied with the given automaton

Comment: `cddr` needs a list of at least two elements. `'((4))` is a list with one element.

Comment: (I'd suggest using a struct, not a list, to hold the automata data. At the very least, [`first`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._first%29%29), `second`, etc. to extract particular elements would be more readable)